# Laravel - Resetting The Array Results

Tags: laravel

Please consider the codes below:

```
$cars = Car::get();
$car_ids = $cars->pluck('id');

$parts = Part::whereIn('car_id', $car_ids)->get();

foreach($cars as $car){
   $part_each = $parts->where('car_id', $car->id)->toArray();

   dump($part_each);
}
```

### With the code above, I am getting:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▶]
]
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:4 [▶]
  2 => array:4 [▶]
]
array:3 [▼
  3 => array:4 [▶]
  4 => array:4 [▶]
  5 => array:4 [▶]
]
```

### What I need is:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▶]
]
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▶]
  1 => array:4 [▶]
]
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▶]
  1 => array:4 [▶]
  2 => array:4 [▶]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$parts` is a collection, you can use [values()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-values) to ignore the key:

```php
$part_each = $parts->where('car_id', $car->id)->values()->all();
```

Comment: haven't used [values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-values) before. exactly what i need. big thumbs up here!